# Pyserial - Send "hello" out TCP socket on connect

Tags: pyserial

I'm having a problem with a PHP socket receiver that is on a remote 3G site.  I am using socat to connect to it however when I reconnect (after a link fail) the remote socket hangs until I send it data, this is problematic as there are multiple hosts that connect to this remote socket.

I would like to have better control over the tcp socket connect component (as a client) hence why I'd like to use pyserial.   What I would like to do is:

1) On successful connection to remote TCP socket,  send "Hello" to remote socket.  This needs to include cr/lf which I believe is x0dx0a
2) Continue on and let pyserial link the serial port to the tcp socket

On reconnect after link fail, send the same message ie: "Hello" with cr/lf

The Hello message (with cr/lf) puts data into the remote socket buffer and it allows it to continue, exactly what I want.

I'm fine on bash script but very light on in python....

Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/examples/tcp_serial_redirect.py

Line 153:165 is the connect code...
Line 183:196 is the linking of serial to tcp

Could anyone please point me into the direction of how to do this....

Thankyou if you can help

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can just add a few lines:

Immediately after the while True statement at line 152, insert the line:

```
say_hello = True
```

then immediately after the try: statement at line 182, insert the following:

```
if say_hello:
    client_socket.sendall(b"Hello.\r\n")
    say_hello = False
```